# VBA sort rows without opening pages

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a problem with my sorting code.
The code runs on different pages in one workbook
The script bugs out if i try to sort without opening the page first.
I would like to sort without opening the pages.
Below is one example of the code for one sheet:

```
'Declaration
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim lastusedcolomb As Integer
'Connection
'compare connection Import
Debug.Print "Connections_Import"
lastusedrow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CompareConnections").Range("A4").End(xlDown).row
lastusedcolomb = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CompareConnections").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
numberofitems = lastusedrow - 3
Debug.Print numberofitems
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CompareConnections").Range("A4:D" & lastusedrow).Sort key1:=Range("A:D"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
orderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Comment: Stop using activeworkbook and explicitly reference your workbooks

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem `key1:=Range("A:D")` -
Change it to `key1:=Sheets("CompareConnections").Range("A:D")`